# Is it possible to install and use the concurrent.futures module?

Tags: python

I'm reading Python documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html and I want to use this feature, but I cannot.

It fails on the first step: importing the module.  For
`import concurrent.futures`
I get

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/kevin/concurrent.py", line 3, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'concurrent.futures'; 'concurrent' is not a package
```

And I cannot get pip to find or install it either, either as 'concurrent.futures' or just as 'concurrent'.

I'm currently on Xubuntu 22.04 LTS, running Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is named `concurrent.py`, which means it implicitly defines a module named `concurrent`, shadowing the builtin `concurrent` package.

Comment: At first I didn't believe it because I had entered the ```import``` command on the command-line.  But of course when Python saw the ```concurrent``` part, it looked for and found my program file in the current directory.   In short: you nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

Never name your file identical to a name of a package. Python follows a certain lock-up order while trying to import modules. The orders starts be default in the current directory from where the program was started. If a Python file with the same name is found there, it will be imported.

So what you are doing here is basically importing your own script. Which works as the name is `concurrent`, but then the exception appears as there is not object within your file called `futures`.

Comment: Thanks for the details of how it works.